# How to extent sample project for IBM Watson Assistant to display more than text answers?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am currently testing the IBM Watson Assistant and one of its [Node.js sample projects](https://github.com/IBM/watson-banking-chatbot).  I have configured options like (options, images, connect to agent and pause) in Watson Assistant. In the sample app, those options are not shown in the chat window. Why? How can I add them to the bot?

Comment: Have you checked that the chatbot app is programmed to handle those objects? What is your question?

Comment: my question when i add a dialog in ibm watson  to show two option's YES and NO if user clicks on yes the value yes will be passed if no value no will be passed .using options feature in ibm . i am trying to see the same in node js output( banking chat bot page) but it is showing noting. This is applicable for options lile(options, images, pause, connect to live agent)

Comment: Please add details, it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: i am trying to see the options like ( image ,options ,pause, connect to agent) which i have configured in iBM watson page  in the end user node js project chat window. currently the response from chat bot( node js  project) for options, pause , images are empty . the chat bot respond for only "text"

Comment: And, have you adapted the Node.js code to display them? Share it

Comment: i don't know where to update the code w.r.t image, pause etc...any help

Comment: From a quick look: https://github.com/IBM/watson-banking-chatbot/blob/master/public/js/conversation.js#L90

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look at the source in https://github.com/IBM/watson-banking-chatbot/blob/master/public/js/conversation.js#L90 it seems that the code only prints out text. See the [IBM Watson Assistant response types](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-api-dialog-responses#api-dialog-responses-types) for how options, images and more are encoded.

It seems you would need to extend the code in how to compose the actual output based on detected response options.